# Create Array and print it into TXT file

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

**UPDATE:**

I get array values from `$_POST['changed']`.

The array structure looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [recid] => 1
            [nachname] => Müller7777
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [recid] => 3
            [vorname] => Maria123
        )

)
```

I get on line #3 this error: **Fatal error: Function name must be a string**

```
$uarr=array();

foreach ($_POST['changed'] as $a) {
  list($x,$k)=array_keys($a);
  list($y,$v)=array_values($a);

  $uarr[$y][]="$k='$v'";
}

foreach ($uarr as $k=>$v) {
  $sql = "";
  $sql .="UPDATE tbl SET ".join(",",$v)." WHERE recid=$k";
  // send UPDATE ...
}
file_put_contents('filename2.txt', $sql);
```

Before I do the final database UPDATE I want to check if the created array does its job. Thats why I want to write the $sql variable first into a txt-file.

### ------------------------------------------------

**SOLUTION:**

checking if `$_POST['changed'] == null` is the final answer for this question.

```
if ($_POST['changed'] == null) {

} else {

$uarr=array();
$b = $_POST['changed'];
foreach ($b as $a) {
  list($x,$k)=array_keys($a);
  list($y,$v)=array_values($a);
  // $x contains the `recid` key 
  // $y ...                  value
  $uarr[$y][]="$k='$v'";
}



foreach ($uarr as $k=>$v) {
  $sql = "";
  $sql .="UPDATE tbl SET ".join(",",$v)." WHERE recid=$k";
  // send UPDATE ...
}
file_put_contents('filename2.txt', $sql);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you run the individual `UPDATE` statements - yes, for each `recid` value you should send one statement - you could first collect all the affected values for each `recid` in an associative array like

```
$uarr=array();
foreach ($_POST['changed'] as $a) {
  list($x,$k)=array_keys($a);
  list($y,$v)=array_values($a);
  // $x contains the `recid` key 
  // $y ...                  value
  $uarr[$y][]="$k='$v'";
}
```

and then do another loop like

```
foreach ($uarr as $k=>$v) {
  $sql="UPDATE tbl SET ".join(",",$v)." WHERE recid=$k";
  // send UPDATE ...
}
```

But, of course, this will only work correctly if the `$_POST('changed')` array adheres to the described format and order. And, finally, so far there is nothing in this code to protect you from SQL injection.

Comment: should `$uarr[$y][]="$k.='$v'";` be in the foreach loop? i think there is a curved clip to much

Comment: Well spotted! I typed this up on my iPod. ... Probably should not have done but could not resist. :) ... and I also removed the `.` in the above statement. That was a typo too.

Comment: yes but i think $_POST('changed') should look like: $_POST['changed'] - when i change this i get `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: grmph... yes of course! Sorry for the messy code but I still believe here is a valid idea behind it. ;-))

Comment: ... and you should place the `$sql ="";` *before* the loop. :)

Comment: Well, if `$_POST['changed']` really contains the numbered array as shown in your post then the `foreach` loop should actually work on that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36618/discussion-between-mike-and-cars10)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this:

```
$BigArray = $_POST['changed'];
$LengthOfArray = sizeof($BigArray);

for ($i = 0; $i < $LengthOfArray ; $i++) {

    $SubArray = $BigArray[$i];

    // Call the update/insert here
    // $SubArray['recid'] is the ID
    // $SubArray['vorname'] is the name
}
```